# SES SMTP mail giving openssl :EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length Error

Tags: yii2, openssl, yii2-advanced-app, amazon-ses, evp-cipher

We are creating Yii2 Rest API. We are implementing SES SMTP. Email is working fine but With API Response, We are getting 500 Internal Server Error with below Fetal Error:

**"Uncaught exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'fgets(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length"**

Complete Error Message coming as below:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'yii\base\ErrorException'
>   with message 'fgets(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages:
>                                                                                 error:0607A082:digital envelope
>   routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length' in
>   /var/www/html/rington/advanced/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:163
>                                                                                 Stack trace:
>                                                                                 #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'fgets(): SSL op...', '/var/www/html/r...', 163, Array)
>                                                                                 #1 /var/www/html/rington/advanced/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(163):
>   fgets(Resource id #31)
>                                                                                 #2 /var/www/html/rington/advanced/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(397):
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->readLine(40)
>                                                                                 #3 /var/www/html/rington/advanced/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(277):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse(40)
>                                                                                 #4 /var/www/html/rington/advanced/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/c in
>   **/var/www/html/rington/advanced/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php**
>   on line **163**

I have tried different Solution given on Google Search but nothing works.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you must be using `php >=7`

Comment: Thanks, But We have multiple site setup on same server so not possible to update PHP version. We are using PHP 5.6.30,  Is there any solution for fixing this

Comment: That was a question actually. can you show the full error trace you receive?

Comment: see this [issue](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/720) if that relates to you

Comment: also have you enabled ssl on your site and in the AWS Ses too?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: I have add complete error trace in Question above.  Yes SSL is enable for Site. I have just setup SES have no idea how to setup ssl with AWS SES. Please guide..Thanks